# Clickable Particle Universe

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, particles, universe

I'm trying to make a universe of messages.
These will be stored in *mongoDB* or so, so you can click any particle and read the message.

Now, I don't know how to get the clicked particle. I tried with intersection but I'm sure I made a mistake somewhere.

Here's the CodePen::
[http://codepen.io/Mr-K/pen/JKZPWK](http://codepen.io/Mr-K/pen/JKZPWK?editors=0010)

The Particle Universe pretty much it's done.
Here's for add particles:

```
  function Particles(num) {
this.particleArray = []
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  var c = getRandomColor();
  var o = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 0 + 1)) / 100;
  var s = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 5 + 1)) + 5;
  var particleCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 250 + 1)) + 250;
  var particle = {
    color: c,
    opacity: o,
    size: s,
    number: particleCount,
    message: 'THIS IS THE PARTICLE: '+particleCount
  }
  this.particleArray.push(particle);
}
```

}

How can I click the particles and show an alert or something, just fire a function with the array described before to pop up the message and the particleCount.

Thanks

Comment: Using a raycaster would be great because then you could detect which (if any) particles are clicked on. Looking up some basic examples will help